# Combinatorics on divisors

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, prime-factorization, integer-lattices

Consider the set $D$ of all divisors of $10000$. What is the number of subsets $H \subseteq D$ containing at least two elements such that for every $a, b \in H$, $a \mid b$ or $b \mid a$?
I tried translating the problem into one about integer grid, which makes it ask for the number of ways to choose at least two points in the square with vertices $(0, 0)$ and $(4,4)$ ordered in such a way that they can be reached sequentially by only moving up and right. But I fail to see a way to calculate it besides setting up this recurrence: let $a_{m,n}$ be the number of subsets of the square between $(0,0)$ and $(m,n)$ that satisfy the above property. We can form such a subset in a number of ways: it could be a subset already counted in $a_{m-1,n}$, or in $a_{m,n-1}$, or one of those same subsets with the addition of $(m,n)$, or be composed of $(m,n)$ and a point in the rectangle with vertices $(0,0$) and $(m, n)$ (there are $(m+1)(n+1)-1$ such points). If we simply added $a_{m-1,n}$ and $a_{m,n-1}$ we would be counting twice the subsets already counted in $a_{m-1, n-1}$.
The recurrence is thus: $\begin{cases} a_{0, 0} = 0 \\ a_{n,0} = a_{0,n} = 2a_{n-1, 0} + n \\ a_{m,n} = 2(a_{m-1,n} + a_{m,n-1} - a_{m-1,n-1}) + (m+1)(n+1)-1\end{cases}$.

And the answer we are looking for is $a_{4,4}$. Is there a more elegant way to answer this however?

Comment: @user376343 I have edited the post. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Outline: for each k, when choosing k points in the (0,0) to (4,4) grid, first choose the x coordinates, then choose the y coordinates. Then sum over k.

Comment: What if two points share the x or y coordinate?

Comment: In case it’s any help, you seem to be asking for the number of cliques (with at least two vertices) in the undirected graph $G$ having $D$ as the vertex set and edges indicating either-direction divisibility. This graph can be generated by taking the transitive closure of the $5\times5$ up/right-directed grid graph on the square you describe (where the divisor $d=2^i 5^j$ is located at the point $(i,j)$) and then ignoring edge direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you'll think this is elegant but here goes:-

For convenience, temporarily drop the restriction that $H$ must contain $2$ elements. We can form a variant on Pascal's triangle as follows.

Write $1$ in the top right square i.e. $(4,4)$. This represents the number of sets $H$ with $(4,4)$ as the 'least' point.

Now consider the squares in the next diagonal down i.e. $(3,4)$ and $(4,3)$. For each of these squares we calculate $1$ more than the sum of the numbers above and to the right of it i.e. a total of $2$. For $(3,4)$, the first $1$ represents the number of sets $H$ which only contain  $(3,4)$. The sum of the other numbers adds up all those sets $H$ containing  $(3,4)$ and at least one other point.

Subsequent diagonals contain the numbers
$$4,6,4$$
$$8,16,16,8$$
$$16,40,52,40,16$$
$$96,152,152,96$$
$$416,504,416$$
$$1536,1536$$
$$5136$$

So, I obtain the number $5136$ in square $(0,0)$ i.e. as the number of sets $H$ with $(0,0)$ as the 'least' point.

That means that the sum of all the numbers in the $5\times 5$ block is $ 5136+5135=10271$. We must now exclude the $5^2$ cases where we have only $1$ element in $H$ giving a total of $10246$.

Comment: Not sure if you still wanted this, but I confirm your numbers in the calculation.

Comment: I had redone them by computer but thanks nevertheless - confirmation is always reassuring!

Comment: Thanks for the idea of including the sets of only one element until the end! Running the calculations, your result is the same as my method's, so I can also confirm your numbers

Comment: That's good. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

I think that $a(5)$ in [this OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A326237) might contain the number you’re looking for, if you subtract from it the $26$ subsets containing fewer than two divisors that satisfy your condition. At least it has the right number, seems related, and seems to be correct for divisors of $2^1 5^1 = 10$ as well. (The number $a(2)$ counts the $12$ subsets of $\{1, 2, 5, 10\}$ not containing both $2$ and $5$.)

The entry for [this OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A084773), whose terms are one-half the values of the one above, gives a generating function and other information you might find useful.

Comment: Nice references! How did you know about these sequences? Do they refer to concepts recurrent in some parts of math?

Comment: I don’t know anything in particular - I just like fun counting questions. Counting paths with various restrictions comes up a lot in combinatorics. Your question seemed interesting and not too obscure, so I searched for $10272$ in OEIS, supposing it was more likely that someone might have considered this without excluding the size $0$ and $1$ subsets.